# Play Framework [2.4.x] OpenID and Oauth -- using PLAINTEXT for oauth_signature_method

Tags: oauth, playframework-2.0, openid

Based on the documentation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaOAuth

I have a Twitter "reader" working without issue. I can authorize "my app" and make calls through the API as expected.

I'm trying to do a similar process with FreshBooks and I seem to hitting an issue with the `oauth_signature_method` being preset to HMAC-SHA1.

As the vendor enforces HTTPS on all API calls they (only) appear to support PLAINTEXT for the `oauth_signature_method`

Working with vendor to confirm this.

Scouring the docs and the code to see if the signature method is somehow selectable and if so when/where would I inject that change into the code?

If anyone else has tripped over this and found the solution it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to: https://github.com/mttkay/signpost/blob/master/signpost-core/src/main/java/oauth/signpost/OAuthConsumer.java there might be hope...

Comment: Question is now: How do we "set" one of these: import oauth.signpost.signature.AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy;
import oauth.signpost.signature.HmacSha1MessageSigner;
import oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner;
**import oauth.signpost.signature.PlainTextMessageSigner;**
import oauth.signpost.signature.QueryStringSigningStrategy;
import oauth.signpost.signature.SigningStrategy;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workable solution posted in github: https://github.com/techmag/OAuthPlainTextCalculator

I'll repeat the code here for your convenience:

```
    class OAuthPlainTextCalculator(consumerKey: ConsumerKey, requestToken: RequestToken) extends WSSignatureCalculator with com.ning.http.client.SignatureCalculator {
  import com.ning.http.client.{ Request, RequestBuilderBase }
  import com.ning.http.util.UTF8UrlEncoder
  import com.ning.http.util.Base64

  val HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization"
  val KEY_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY = "oauth_consumer_key"
  val KEY_OAUTH_NONCE = "oauth_nonce"
  val KEY_OAUTH_SIGNATURE = "oauth_signature"
  val KEY_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD = "oauth_signature_method"
  val KEY_OAUTH_TIMESTAMP = "oauth_timestamp"
  val KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token"
  val KEY_OAUTH_VERSION = "oauth_version"

  val OAUTH_VERSION_1_0 = "1.0"
  val OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD = "PLAINTEXT"

  protected final val nonceBuffer: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](16)

  override def calculateAndAddSignature(request: Request, requestBuilder: RequestBuilderBase[_]): Unit = {
    val nonce: String = generateNonce
    val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L
    val signature = calculateSignature(request.getMethod, request.getUrl, timestamp, nonce, request.getFormParams, request.getQueryParams)
    val headerValue = constructAuthHeader(signature, nonce, timestamp)
    requestBuilder.setHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, headerValue);
  }

  /**
   * from http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process
   * oauth_signature is set to the concatenated encoded values of the
   * Consumer Secret and Token Secret,
   * separated by a ‘&’ character (ASCII code 38),
   * even if either secret is empty.
   * The result MUST be encoded again.
   */

  def calculateSignature(method: String, baseURL: String, oauthTimestamp: Long, nonce: String, formParams: java.util.List[com.ning.http.client.Param], queryParams: java.util.List[com.ning.http.client.Param]) = {
    val signedText = new StringBuilder(100)
    signedText.append(consumerKey.secret)
    signedText.append('&');
    signedText.append(requestToken.secret)
    UTF8UrlEncoder.encode(signedText.toString)
  }

  def constructAuthHeader(signature: String, nonce: String, oauthTimestamp: Long, sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder) = {
    constructAuthHeader_sb(signature, nonce, oauthTimestamp).toString
  }

  def constructAuthHeader_sb(signature: String, nonce: String, oauthTimestamp: Long, sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(250)) = {
    sb.synchronized {
      sb.append("OAuth ")

      sb.append(KEY_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY)
      sb.append("=\"")
      sb.append(consumerKey.key)
      sb.append("\", ")

      sb.append(KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN)
      sb.append("=\"")
      sb.append(requestToken.token)
      sb.append("\", ")

      sb.append(KEY_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD)
      sb.append("=\"")
      sb.append(OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD)
      sb.append("\", ")

      // careful: base64 has chars that need URL encoding:
      sb.append(KEY_OAUTH_SIGNATURE)
      sb.append("=\"");
      sb.append(signature)
      sb.append("\", ")

      sb.append(KEY_OAUTH_TIMESTAMP)
      sb.append("=\"")
      sb.append(oauthTimestamp)
      sb.append("\", ")

      // also: nonce may contain things that need URL encoding (esp. when using base64):
      sb.append(KEY_OAUTH_NONCE)
      sb.append("=\"");
      sb.append(UTF8UrlEncoder.encode(nonce))
      sb.append("\", ")

      sb.append(KEY_OAUTH_VERSION)
      sb.append("=\"")
      sb.append(OAUTH_VERSION_1_0)
      sb.append("\"")
      sb
    }
  }

  def generateNonce = synchronized {
    scala.util.Random.nextBytes(nonceBuffer)
    // let's use base64 encoding over hex, slightly more compact than hex or decimals
    Base64.encode(nonceBuffer)
  }
}

object OAuthPlainTextCalculator {
  def apply(consumerKey: ConsumerKey, token: RequestToken): WSSignatureCalculator = {
    new OAuthPlainTextCalculator(consumerKey, token)
  }
}
```

Comment: Note the github repo ha updates whereas over time this answer may not -- see the repo if you want to use the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 2/3s of the solution is to hack the code as follows:

```
  val serviceInfo = ServiceInfo(
      "https://sample.freshbooks.com/oauth/oauth_request.php",
      "https://sample.freshbooks.com/oauth/oauth_access.php",
      "https://sample.freshbooks.com/oauth/oauth_authorize.php", KEY)

  val provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(serviceInfo.requestTokenURL, serviceInfo.accessTokenURL, serviceInfo.authorizationURL)

  val consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(serviceInfo.key.key, serviceInfo.key.secret)

  consumer.setMessageSigner(new PlainTextMessageSigner())

  def retrieveAccessToken(token: RequestToken, verifier: String): Either[OAuthException, RequestToken] = {
          consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token.token, token.secret)
          try {
              provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);
              Right(new RequestToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret()))
          } catch {
              case ex: OAuthException => Left(ex)
          }
      }

      def retrieveRequestToken(callbackURL: String): Either[OAuthException, RequestToken] = {
        try {
            provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, callbackURL)
            Right(new RequestToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret()))
        } catch {
            case ex: OAuthException => Left(ex)
        }
      }
```

I say 2/3s because the final piece of the puzzle uses `OAuthCalculator`

```
    WS.url("https://sample.freshbooks.com/api/2.1/xml-in")
      .sign(OAuthCalculator(KEY, credentials))
      .post(data)
      .map(result => Ok(result.body))
  }
```

and I can't find way to change that -- I might have to rewrite the entire class or create a new one. It seems strange that we have two methods doing basically the same thing one way and a one method doing it completely differently.

This is a total hack as we should just be able to put

```
consumer.setMessageSigner(new PlainTextMessageSigner())
```

right into the initial code